# JSON parsing the content inside the variable?

Tags: javascript, json

Say I have the following code:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var responses = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var passwordIs = responses.email; // email should be replaced with the user's input value;
            document.write(passwordIs);
         }
    };
xmlhttp.open("GET","https://example.com", true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

How can I make it run such that when the user puts in an email, the email in the variable `passwordIs` gets replaced with the input?

To put it in simpler terms, when user enters `jdoe@example.com`, the variable `passwordIs` should "see" this: `responses.jdoe@example.com` Instead, it is "seeing" `responses.email`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use brackets instead of a dot:

```
var passwordIs = responses[email];
```

With dot notation, Javascript interprets the text after the dot as a literal, so you can't use a variable; see [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)